# Any guides on learning how to interpret a SQL query's Execution Plan in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, sql-execution-plan

Is there any good article, tutorial or similar references on interpreting the Execution Plan of a query in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Red Gate offers a [free e-book](http://downloads.red-gate.com/ebooks/HighPerformanceSQL_ebook.zip) on exactly this  :)

Comment: Oh. My. God. Just browsing through e-book shows it contains a lot of information I've been looking for on execution plans. Thank you!